# Temporarily Remove pseudo CSS with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a dropdown list that uses some :before and :after pseudo CSS to create a arrow. When a checkbox is checked this dropdown becomes disabled and everything turns lightgray except for the :before and :after pseudo CSS they stay the original colors. I know what needs to be disabled in the CSS I'm just unsure how to do this so the CSS will return to normal if the checkbox is unchecked.

**Current Code** which currently doesn't remove the :before and :after
**JQuery**

```
$('#checkBox').click(function () {
        if ($("#checkBox").is(":checked")) {
            $('#dropDown')
                .prop('disabled', true)
                .removeClass('dropdown')
                .addClass('dropdownDisabled')
                .val("");
        }
        else {
             $('#dropDown')
                .prop('disabled', false);
            }
});
```

**CSS**

```
.dropdown:disabled {
    box-shadow:none;
}

.dropdownDisabled:before {
    content:none;
}
.dropdownDisabled:after {
    content:none;
}
```

**CSS to create arrows**

```
.dropdown:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 8px;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid #fff;
}

.dropdown:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 3px;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid #333;
}
```

Comment: have you tried setting content to "" and maybe add display: hidden; and/or visibility: hidden; ?

Comment: Where is your CSS to create the arrows?

Comment: maybe also add the id selector to make it more specific: #dropDown.dropdownDisabled:after

Comment: added the CSS for the arrows

Comment: you're not removing the `dropdownDisabled` class on the dropdown. add `.removeClass('dropdownDisabled')` after you do `.prop('disabled', false)`

Comment: @Alex I added `.removeClass('#dropDown.dropdown:before')` and `.addClass('#dropDown.dropdownDisabled:before')` to remove the pseudo classes but it didn't seem to work

Comment: @haxxxton That seems like it would work to get the CSS back to normal thanks I'll try that once I am able to remove it when the checkbox is checked

Comment: try `display:none;` instead of `content:none;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple toggleClass?

```
$('#checkBox').click(function () {
    if ($("#checkBox").is(":checked")) {
        $('#dropDown')
            .toggleClass('dropdownDisabled')
            .prop('disabled', true)
            .val("");
    }
    else {
         $('#dropDown')
            .toggleClass('dropdownDisabled')
            .prop('disabled', false);
        }
});
```

Comment: Very nice I did not know about `.toggleClass` that worked great thank you